# Qt Qprocess how to launch startx and take back control without detached

Tags: qt, process, qt4, qt5, qprocess

My program is receiving orders from a TCP socket and one of them is "launch startx" but it shouldn't cut the main process from continuing, i tried with startDetached but in the future my application should be able to kill the programm, and calling  `process->kill()` doesn't seem to work on a detached process, the problem with non detached is that my programm waits for the QProcess to terminate before starting the other commands using startx.
with a terminal here are the commands i would like to achieve :

```
startx&
somecommands_that_need_startx
fg
Ctr_c
```

edit : Here is what i have tried, using the pid of the detached process :

```
   QString cmd;
QStringList args;
cmd = "startx";
args << "";
qint64 pid_cur;
    p->startDetached(cmd,args,"/",&pid_cur);
    //p->execute(cmd,args);
    std::cout << "pid_cur : " << QString::number(pid_cur).toStdString();
//then in a console i have tried kill -9 pid_cur it told me pid_cur didnt exist
    p->waitForFinished(-1);
//some command
    QProcess killer;
    std::cout << QString::number(pid).toStdString() << std::endl;
    QString cmd;
    QStringList args;
    cmd = "kill -9 ";
    args << QString::number(pid);
    killer.startDetached(cmd,args);
```

So do you think startdetached is the right way ? in this case how can i kill the process ? or should i use a simple start with something else ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use startDetached for startx and store process pid.
[If the function is successful then *pid is set to the process identifier of the started process.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached)

Comment: I have tried this but the id that is getting stored is not the real one (i tried to kill -9 it) and not 0 either. I am posting the code.

Comment: Have you checked exit code that your startx is actually gets started? Common error could be that you need provide full path to binary. For kill command should be something similar to:
cmd="/bin/kill";
args << "-9" << pid;

Comment: well the startx command actually works since i verifiy on the main screen, the kill command doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: it really looks like pid is not filled properly by startDetached (or maybe QString is not interpreting this number the right way)

Comment: What pid did you see in cout output? What pid actually startx has `ps aux | grep startx`? Can you also `qDebug() << pid;` ?

Comment: i tried qDebug()<<pid; but i don't know how to compile with debug, let me check, the pid startx has is 33420 whereas ps faux tells me it has 3361

Comment: ok qDebug tells me quite the same thing than cout for pid, exept it doesnt have the last 0... so casting into a string / QString adds this 0. The pid given by debug actually corresponds to :
`\_ xinit /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc -- /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /home/meralli/.serverauth.4548`
So i guess this number after serverauth must be a pid, but killing it doesnt kill startx

Comment: Ok than you probably want to determine parent of pid [like in](http://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line) or to just lookup for pid quering ps. Or you could probably start QProcess in own thread and use start

Comment: I had another idea, i tried using killall -9, when i use it in a terminal "killall -9 X" it works but when i do a process with it, nothing happens, any idea ?

Comment: There are would be reasons:
- Terminal and QProcess has different environments
- You killing process which has root rights
- Have you checked QProcess exit codes and std out/err output?

Answer (score 0):

You should add -9 as argument for your killer process:

```
QString cmd="kill";
QStringList args = QStringList() << "-9" << QString::number(pid);
killer.startDetached(cmd, args);
```

When you use "cmd -9" QProcess tries to launch "cmd -9" as one command not a command with -9 parameter